# How to provide service in another service

Tags: angular, http

Hello angular experts.

I want to use service in another service like global variable.

[image]

This code is part of my `LoginService`.

And `globalService` has my server url.

And then i run this code. Chrome show me `Error: No provider for GlobalService!`.

I know if i use service i should write `providers:[]` in component.

But this case is not normal. Service has another service.

Please help me. Thanks you.

Comment: use @Inject there. 
i.e
`@Inject(GlobalService) global:GlobalService`

Comment: `@Inject(GlobalService) private global:GlobalService` like this?

Comment: Yes...
Inside constructor after HttpClient

Comment: `constructor (private http: HttpClient, @Inject(GlobalService) private global:GlobalService)`

I wrote this code, but It did not works. Chrome show same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your module ( probably AppModule), add your GlobalService in the `provider`.
You should not add your provider in your Component/Service as it will give you different instance of that service!

Comment: What i meant is component/service

Comment: Why not relevant? If it solved your problem. The answer I provide is the solution for your error Error: No provider for GlobalService!

Comment: @ParthGhiya it is just a typo error, but whether it is a component/service, the error speaks for itself

Comment: I was a little confused, thanks your answer. your answer works. thanks

Comment: Can I ask one question? I wrote provider at app.module.ts.
What does your `component / service` mean?
I think `login-bar / login-service`. It is right?

Comment: You can use your GlobalService in another Service or Component, that's what I mean. The error you got is that a service should be provided somewhere and that's the NgModule

Comment: Yes, you can use the GlobalService in your LoginBarComponent or LoginService

Comment: If i use `GlobalService` only in `Login`, I "can" write `LoginModule`.
But If i use `GlobalService` anywhere, I "should" write `AppModule`.

is right?

Comment: The easy answer is yes. It gets complicated on how you setup your loginmodule because you can also provide the globalservice there. I just assume that you provide it in your AppModule because that's what everyone is doing.